# T-SQL Sorting by year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting

I would like to sort by date according to date yyyy,mm.
I tried using VARCHARS first:

```
GROUP BY (YEAR(join_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(join_date) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

But converting them to varchar meant my sort went like
 2014.1 - 2014.11 - 2014.12 - 2014.2 
How could I sort them in properly by year then month order?

```
SELECT Year(join_date) + MONTH(join_date) AS Date, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM X
WHERE mtype ='A' AND (join_date BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -5, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(join_date) + MONTH(join_date)
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't need to convert them to varchar, `YEAR` and `MONTH` return ints:

```
SELECT Year(join_date) As JoinedYear, MONTH(join_date) AS JoinedMonth, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM X
WHERE mtype ='A' AND (join_date BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -5, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(join_date), MONTH(join_date)
ORDER BY YEAR(join_date) ASC, MONTH(join_date) ASC
```

Comment: That gives me 'invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' wouldn't this simply add 2014.02 to be 2016 ?

Comment: @user5350968: i have edited my answer. You should not group by `Year+Month` but by `Year,Month`

Comment: The error was my mistake, but it does add year and month together making Feb 2014 a number 2016

Comment: @user5350968: you are selecting `year + month` which is pointless, you dont want to add them. Select two columns

Comment: the reason I wanted year+month in one field is because I'm working on a result set for a graph that takes one column as x and count as y data but thank you anyway